# Uninstalling Schlage doorhandle

Tags: doors

I am getting stuck when trying to uninstall my Schlage doorhandle.  I have gotten the actual handles and plates off, but can't figure out how to remove the cylinder. I have attached some pictures, and I assume it might require removing the little locking pins, but I have been unable to get those out easily. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Side with locking pins:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I ended up doing this and was able to remove the cylinder.

Answer (score 1):

What you call locking pins are known as cotter pins.  It is recommended they are only single use only.  Use new ones if they are removed.

Can straighten them out and pull out or use something that fits in the loop and use something to tap them out.

If too bent, then snip the ends off and remove.

Replace with new ones of a similar size.